# How to put php variable to html code

Tags: php

This is a part of my php source code.
I don't know how to put variation inside to echo function.

```
<?php 
$putMeInside = "please";
?>

<?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo
        "<tr>
        <div onClick=\"saveToDatabase(this,'name','777')\">{$row['name']}</div>
        </tr>\n";
      }
?>
```

How can I **$putMeInside** value to the place of '777' (parameter of saveToDatabase function) ?

Too simple question to some people, but I don't know it really. I tried over 15 times edit on and on, But couldn't find result. please help me...

Comment: `echo
        "<tr>
        <div onClick=\"saveToDatabase(this,'name','{$putMeInside}')\">{$row['name']}</div>
        </tr>\n";`

Comment: Don't need curly brackets for a variable that isn't part of an array: `saveToDatabase(this,'name','$putMeInside')` will do fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
echo "
<tr>
    <div onClick="saveToDatabase(this,'name','$putMeInside')\">
    {
        $row['name']
    }
    </div> 
</tr>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo
        "<tr>
        <div onClick=\"saveToDatabase(this,'name','" . $putMeInside . "')\">{$row['name']}</div>
        </tr>\n";
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo
        "<tr>
        <div onClick=\"saveToDatabase(this,'name','$putMeInside')\">{$row['name']}</div>
        </tr>\n";
```